# Unable to add and delete columns in tanstack table v8. Not sure how to work with generic types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table, react-table-v8

I am trying to create a table using tanstack table v8 where I can

- add columns of types **text, number** and **select**
- delete columns
- add rows

Since I have less experience in typescript, I am struggling with defining generic types that can work with any kind of table type.

I tried to follow the example in https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/examples/react/editable-data but did not know how to change the explicit type declaration of Person to a generic type that is stored in the backend and updated by the user dynamically